# How to get Next button to go to next anchor on the page w jQuery

Tags: jquery, button, anchor

http://jsfiddle.net/lizyo/geYka/18/

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.steps-content').css('display', 'none');
      $('#step_00').css('display', 'block');
   });

   $(document).on('click', '#steps-subnav li', function () {
      $('#steps-subnav li').removeClass('highlighted');
      $(this).addClass('highlighted');
   });

   $(document).on('click', '#steps-subnav a', function () {
      var linknum = $(this).attr('class').split('_')[1];
      $('#step_' + linknum).css('display', 'block');
      $('.steps-content').not("#step_" + linknum).css('display', 'none');
   });
```

I've setup a subnav pane with jQuery to (1) highlight the navlink (2) display the related content.

Now, I'm struggling to get the NEXT button to work to automatically take me to the next topic.

I'm (obviously!) new to JQUERY.  Would appreciate any tips.  Or suggestions on how to improve my existing code for the subnav.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).on('click', '#next', function () {

    var highlighted = $("#steps-subnav li").filter(".highlighted"),
        next = (highlighted.length > 0) ? highlighted.next() : $("#steps-subnav li:first");

    next.trigger("click");
    next.find("a").trigger("click");

});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/geYka/19/)

Comment: @LizYo great! close this question if there is nothing further.

Comment: Will close. Apologies, I'm wildly new to this... If it's not a huge pain, would you mind explaining the var next = line?  This works so well, but I'd love to know what's actually happening in that line. Thanks!

Comment: I'm declaring two variables - `highlighted` and `next`. `highlighted` is assigned the of `li` which currently has the `highlighted` class. The variable `next` is assigned the `li` which sites next to the element in `highlighted` variable, this uses a condition to check if there are any `li`'s with the `highlighted` class, if there are any such elements the next element is assigned and if not, the first `li` in the list is assigned. @LizYo

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.red-button', function () {
        var $current = $('#steps-subnav li.highlighted');
        $('#steps-subnav .highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');

        var $next = $current.is(':last-child')? $('#steps-subnav li:first').next(): $current.next();
        $next.addClass('highlighted');
        $next.children('a').trigger("click");
    });
```